# Add support for Stack Snippets on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, stack-snippets

When I view a post including a Stack Snippet, there is no ability to "run" the snippet like on the website.

On the app:

[image: No Stack Snippets]

On the mobile site:

[image: Stack Snippets and Unicorns]

Comment: Is that even allowed? I always thought Apple doesn't allow running dynamic code, even javascript, unless it is in a web view.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Isn’t that what a Stack Snippet is — A web view?

Comment: @Pat can't see how this can be true, most basic example is browser app like Chrome which renders JS on iOS just fine. Not sure how easy or feasible it is for an app to render JS, but surely it's possible. Maybe you're confused with Flash, which is indeed not allowed?

Comment: Nah, I read there is a restriction on executing dynamic code other than in a web view. That is what Chrome uses (they are not allowed to use their own render engine as far as I know for this specific reason).

Comment: @Sha it seems that rule was dropped with iOS 8: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/01/new-chrome-for-ios-is-finally-as-fast-and-stable-as-safari/.

Comment: @Pat huh, never noticed any of this. One never stop learning! :)

Comment: If the snippet is pure JS, you don't even need a webview to evaluate it.  You can use a `JSContext` in the [`JavaScriptCore`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/index.html) framework.

Comment: @JAL but a pure JS snippet needs DOM access, too.